# If f is a contraction map on X and g commutes with f, does g have a unique fixed point?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

$(X,d)$ is a complete metric space. If $f:X\rightarrow X$, $g:X\rightarrow X$ and g commutes with f, does g have a unique fixed point?

I've shown that g must have a fixed point for the same value of x such that $f(x)=x$ however I'm struggling to prove that this is unique/find a counter example.

Comment: How about taking $g = \mathrm{id}$?

Comment: Oh yeah, of course.